# How to show that these two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ exist

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, semi-decidability

I came across this problem which asks to show the existence of two disjoint Turing-recognizable sets $A$ and $B$ such that no decidable set $C$ can separate them...

In this case, a set $C$ is said to separate $A$ and $B$ if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq \overline{C}$ ... If only $A$ is Turing-recognizable, then we could easily set $A$ to be $A_{TM}$ and $B$ as $\overline{A_{TM}}$. However, in this case both $A$ and $B$ are Turing-recognizable .... I think that $A$ and $B$ should be constructed using diagonalization, but could not think of a way to do it ... Any help ?

Comment: You can find some example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_inseparable_sets).